# How to speed up operations on many short substrings of a parent string in Python

Tags: python, string, slice

A loop that operates on many but short substrings of a parent string is showing up in the profile and I want to optimize this by avoiding copies. I do need some `string` operations on the slices such as `strip` etc before running the actual operation.

I explored slice of `memoryviews` but it seems `tobytes` again creates a copy. I cant think of a way to call the string operations on the slice without invoking `tobytes` on the memoryview slice. Are there pure Python way of avoiding the copy ?

The un-optimized code would look something like the following

```
 # parent_str is about 4GB
 hash_list = []
 for start,end in offset_list:
   segment = parent_str[start:end].strip().replace("%$@", "")
   hash_list.append(hash(segment))
```

Comment: Can you show a small code example that illustrates the issue?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Just did although the example is a gross simplification

Comment: You can ensure python reuses individual strings with `sys.intern`, does that help?

Comment: May I ask why you want to avoid the slicing operation being one more copy? AFAIK any string operation causes a copy. So why the effort to avoid the slicing being one more? If `segment` is indeed short that should not cause any problems.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Ah! good call on intern. I will not be having a lot of repeats so not sure if it will help.

Comment: @PeterE The loop is showing up in the profile so I have to figure out a way to make it faster. Elliminating copies seems like a good candidate. The parent string is readonly so the application does not need to make copies ,although the code is simpler if one does. Now I am in the stage where the code is correct, now have to  make it fast

Comment: But once you apply things like `replace` to a substring it is not a substring any more how could ever you get around that? Also is the slow down really because of the operations inside the loop or merely because it is a loop with a lot of iterations?

Comment: @PeterE If I knew I wouldn't be asking the question would I ? If anything about the question is unclear let me know. The processing does not require copy, the question is can I avoid (some of) the copies in pure Python with speedup in mind. If you could answer that as a categorical yes or a no, please do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a set to store the substrings, it will automatically get rid of the duplicates

```
>>> string = "This is a string with duplicates with duplicates"
>>> substrings = set(string.split())
>>> substrings
{'This', 'duplicates', 'a', 'string', 'is', 'with'}
>>> substrings.add('hello')
>>> substrings.add('duplicates')
>>> substrings
{'This', 'duplicates', 'hello', 'a', 'string', 'is', 'with'}
```

Comment: I don't think deduplication is the issue here.